# Update SharePoint Column Values with Excel VBA

Tags: excel, sharepoint-online, vba

I have successfully written some VBA code in an Excel Workbook that saves the workbook into a SharePoint List using values in specific cells to generate the file name, this was pretty straight forward:

```
Sub submitapproval()
ThisPath = "https://recupeit.sharepoint.com/sales/Costing%20Sheets/"
ThisRep = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Quotation").Range("E11").Value
ThisCustomer = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Quotation").Range("B8").Value
ThisDescription = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Quotation").Range("B9").Value
ThisCost = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Hardware Costing Sheet").Range("J25").Value
ThisTotal = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Hardware Costing Sheet").Range("E25").Value

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=ThisPath & ThisCustomer & " - " & 
ThisDescription & ".xlsm"

End Sub
```

The document library I am uploading to has 3 columns which I need to populate with data from the workbook the values for which I already have:

```
ThisRep
ThisCost
ThisTotal
```

I cant find any simple answers on how to achieve this. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks,
Steven